# How Do I Use Selected Radio Button To Navigate Between Views In Mvc5

Tags: radio-button, asp.net-mvc-5

please can i use a selected radio button to navigate into the view bind to it?(am new in MVC)

i Have a page that contains 2 radio button i want to code bind it to different view that when a radio button is selected and then click the button below it will take you to the view bind to that particular radio button else return error that you must select one of the radio button, *e.g payment page that has **Bank payment & E-Payment**, when the BANK-PAYMENT radio button is selected, then click on a button GO, i want to bring a view that contains form for filling the bank details & same as E-Payment*

please i will appreciate Any help you can give on this thanks in advance...

this is my MVC5 code

`

```
                <div>
                    <h4 class="center">Amount</h4>
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Amount, new { @readonly = "readonly"})
                </div>
                <div class="span12"></div>
                <h4 class=" center">Payment Method</h4>
                <div>
                    @Html.RadioButton("PaymentMethod", "/E-Recharge", new { @class = "radio" }) <strong>E-Recharge</strong>
                </div>
                <div>
                    @Html.RadioButton("PaymentMethod", "/Bank", new { @class = "radio" }) <strong>Bank Deposit</strong>
                </div>
                <div class="span5"></div>
                <div class="controls">
                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-large btn-block" value="Order" />
                </div>

            </div>
            }
        </div>`
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to achieve your goal.

**Approach #1**

The first approach is to attach a client-side **click** event on the two radio buttons. Have some jQuery figure out which of the two buttons has been clicked and trigger a `windows.location.href`

This approach causes a full refresh of the page so you need to be aware of that.

**Approach #2**

The second approach is somewhat similar to approach #1 but instead of using a `windows.location.href` simply trigger an **AJAX call** to your Controller/ActionResult which in turn would return a partial view. Place the resulting HTML of the partial view into a `<div>` located underneath the radio buttons (or wherever).

This approach does not cause a full refresh of the page but causes an AJAX call.

**Approach #3**

Assuming your View is strongly typed on a `ViewModel`. While you are populating that `ViewModel` inside your ActionResult, **prepare** both possibilities and render both possibilities inside `hidden <div>’s` which you just have to toggle between `.show()` and `.hide()` based on which radio button is selected.

This approach does not cause a full refresh of the page nor does it need an AJAX call because you, beforehand, prepared both possibilities while populating your ViewModel.

Depending on the complexity of those two possibilities (Views or PartialViews), this can drastically increase the time it takes for the page to loaded properly.

You should now have enough information to help you make the proper decision and test these different approaches.

Comment: Thank you very mush Sir, but i will like to see some code example please... and please i want to know if it not possible to bind the action to a button?? if possible please i will like to have an example on how tis been done

Comment: Unfortunately, I can’t show you code because I don’t know which of the 3 approaches you will take. Based on the approach the code will change and I can’t show you the code for all of them (I don’t have that time). But you can start Googling for how to bind a click event in jQuery on a submit button or on a regular button or directly on radio buttons. You’ll find plenty of examples. This is a start

Comment: ok but would have prefer the #3 Approach... anyway i will check on Google also thank again for your help